# Raspberry Pi with USB 3 (or 3.1) and enough power to use 2 drives

Tags: power, hard-drive, data-transfer

I bought a new camera which writes a lot of data onto SSDs, which I then would like to transfer onto HDDs.

I thought about using a Raspberry Pi, but I was told it doesn't have enough power for a ssd and an hdd. And that it has very slow data transfer rates.

Are there plans from the RPI Foundaiton to bring a USB3 or even USB-C Raspberry Pi soon?

Or do you have alternatives how I could do this? It needs to be powered off of a powerbank/larger lipo.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not in hurry, then the RPi Foundation releases a new product every Pi-Day on 3/14. So then you will see what they will be realeasing.

Currently the VideoCore IV SoC is the limiting factor. The ARM CPU is back packed on that. All I/O and memory access has to go through it. Due to its age it only supports USB 2.0 and 1GB DDR2 RAM. As the DDR2 RAM is getting harder and harder to get the Raspberry Pi as we know it will no more evolve but needs a radical cut.

Rumors indicate that the next Raspberry Pi model might drop VideoCore IV and ARM entirely and use the open source CPU architecture RISC-V instead. Therefore the [RPi Foundation joined the RISC-V Foundation](https://riscv.org/2019/01/hackster-io-article-raspberry-pi-becomes-a-member-of-the-risc-v-foundation/).

Comment: Oh, risc-v would be nice. Yeah, we will mainly need it in summer 2020. So we have plenty of time. But the earlyer the better for bug testing :)

Comment: While the Rpi is great for education, there are a wide variety of other single board computers that might work for your application. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_single-board_computers and I'm sure there's more not on that list.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the most widespread high-performace RPi competitor is [ODROID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODROID). They have already released several boards with 1 and 2 USB3 ports.

Note that you won't be able to run Rasbpian on ODROID, or use all RPi accessories with it. Notably, you won't be able to use the RPi camera with it.

Comment: Sounds good, do you think it can run two external drives from the point of power? Sadly the shipping is quite expansive...